# How to call different login redirect for different role

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.x

App Controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components= array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' =>array('controller' => 'Item' , 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' =>array('controller' => 'Item' , 'action' => 'index'),
    'authError' => 'Login Error',
    'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('login');

    }
}
```

User Controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
    public $name= 'Users';
    public function login(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->Redirect());
            }
            else{

                $this->Session->setFlash('error');
            }
        }

    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->User->recursive=0;
        $this->set('users',$this->User->find('all'));

    }
}
```

there is two types of role in user table admin and customer ,
if admin is logged in loginredirect is `'loginRedirect' =>array('controller' => 'Item' , 'action' => 'index')` . 
if customer is logged in `'loginRedirect' =>array('controller' => 'customer' , 'action' => 'view') .`

user login is depends upon role .

how to give loginredirect based on role

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this in UsersController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

parent::beforeFilter();

   if($this->Acl->check('role','A1')){

        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
        'controller' => 'customer',
        'action' => 'view'
        );

   }elseif($this->Acl->check('role','A2')){
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
        );
   }


}
```

Comment: Error : Call to a member function check() on a non-object . Can you Write full code for AppController and UserController .

Comment: How do you specify your roles?

Comment: role is taking from role column from the table users .

Comment: I think you should check out these information about Access Control List (Acl) it is written,you don't have to rewrite yours. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html